# R: ggplot2 plotting 1 combined boxplot instead of 2 plots for 2 categories

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

This is probably a simple problem with a simple fix, but I cannot seem to get it right for some reason. I am trying to plot a continuous variable "cnt" against a categorical variable "yr" with 2 categories (1 or 2). The data is roughly split in half into year 1 and year 2.

When I try the following code to compare the boxplots over 2 years, I get the following graph however:

```
ggplot(data=rawd,aes(x=yr,y=cnt, color=yr))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  labs(x='Year', y= 'Hourly Usage Count')
```

[image: Boxplot from ggplot2]

I am not sure why that is the case. When I try to visualize it in any other format (such as using jitter or geom_point) there is a clear split between yr=1 and yr= 2 (see below)
[image: jitter plot from ggplot2]
I am also facing an issue when using the simple boxplot command on R, where I get the following curve:

```
boxplot(rawd$yr, rawd$cnt)
```

[image: simple boxplot]

If anyone can see what I am doing wrong, please let me know.

Comment: You need column `yr` to be of type `factor`.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment changing the 'yr' column in question to type 'factor' seems to fix it